# How to plot data from separate files and axis intervals onto one chart?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office, charts, office365, microsoft-excel-365

I am running a simulation that exports data as a csv file(things like elapsed time, energy etc).

I have a few million rows of data (but only 5-6 columns), meaning I cannot actually open this file in Excel because of how large it is.

This is further complicated by the fact that the data is recorded at random intervals which the simulation chooses. For example, the data maybe be at intervals of 0s, 0.3s, 0.7s or even 200s in the file.

How can I plot graphs from multiple runs into 1 graph of x against time or something to that effect to present it nicely? Thank you!

I am currently using Office 365.

Please ask for clarifications if I am not clear enough as I am new here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I realised this is unnecessarily complex to do in Excel.

I personally found it much easier to import the csv file into a Pandas data frame then use MatPlotLib to plot the data into the graphs I want. This is particularly useful as Pandas Dataframes can accommodate up to 100 GB of data per frame. Hope this can be useful for someone facing a similar problem in the future!